# AS3 - How do you receive parameters in a swf from a GET request?

Tags: actionscript-3, get, loaderinfo

I tried using `var params: Object = ((this.stage.loaderInfo) as LoaderInfo).parameters;` to get the parameters, but it returns an Object with no properties. That LoaderInfo will give me the correct URL without the parameters though if I use LoaderInfo.url.  I'm using the request: http://localhost/foo.swf?start=foobar. params.hasOwnProperty("start") returns nothing, and using a for loop shows that "params" has no properties. How do I receive the start/foobar pair in my code? I would much prefer to not use FlashVars due to our setup.

Comment: The method you describe is entirely correct, have you made sure that the entire swf is loaded before you attempt to access the loaderInfo property?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you must embed the SWF into an HTML document, then access the url string as you describe.