# How to relay request in as3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I need to pass along an incoming xml post request using as3? Is there a simple way to just pass that request through an as3 application? I don't want to do anything with the request other than send it along to its destination.

Comment: What do you mean by 'pass along'?  You're being very vague in your description.

Comment: What is your destination?  How is the App getting the request?

Comment: There is a flash app sending a request to the as3 app. The as3 app needs to send the request (as is) to another application.

Comment: @chobo How is the Flash App sendig a request to the AS3 app?  LocalConnection?

Comment: Flash is sending an xml request via POST? To be honest I'm not sure if that is Flash or Java or some combination. It's third-party. I just want to know how to handle incoming requests in actionscript. It's super easy in c#.

Comment: I don't know what you're getting at by making a distinction between a "flash app" and an "as3 app". Do you mean a swf compiled in Flash vs one done using the Flex SDK? Because it's ActionScript either way.

Comment: you need to handle requested XML from a server , or send it to a server ? ( or both ? )

Comment: I thought this was a simple question but from all the confusion I think this is probably not possible... I guess I am thinking too much in c# / java and not in terms of flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're asking (some code would be helpful) but in the meantime I think these could be helpful to you:

[AS3 - How do you receive parameters in a swf from a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673660/as3-how-do-you-receive-parameters-in-a-swf-from-a-get-request)

[Passing params to an external swf via loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558369/passing-params-to-an-external-swf-via-loader)

Comment: From the above conversation I gather that you can only pass "parameters" into Flash you can't actually handle an incoming POST request, or somehow extract POST data from a request.

Comment: I don't want to definitely say you can't do this because I'm not sure, but I certainly don't think Flash is the right tool for this. Accepting incoming requests pretty much means you're writing a web server (or at least a proxy) and so that's a job for server-side languages like Java, not client-side languages like ActionScript.